# pandas dataframe datetime - convert string to datetime offset

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta, datetimeoffset

I have a dataframe like:

| This time | Time difference |
| --- | --- |
| 2000-01-01 00:00:00 | -3:00 |
| 2000-03-01 05:00:00 | -5:00 |
| ... | ... |
| 2000-01-24 16:10:00 | -7:00 |

I'd like to convert the 2nd column (-3:00 means minus 3 hours) from string into something like a time offest that I can directly use to operate with the 1st column (which is already in datetime64[ns]).

I thought there was supposed to be something in pd that does it but couldn't find anything straightforward. Does anyone have any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pd.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```py
df['Time difference'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time difference']+':00')
```

---

Obs: I used `+ ':00'` because the default format for string conversion in `pd.to_timedelta` is "hh:mm:ss".